# unable to connect to AWS EC2 server from putty from work place

Tags: putty, amazon-ec2

Hi I'm trying to connect to AWS EC2 instance using putty by giving authenticate PPK file. getting an error unable to connect to server name host not found, i'm trying to connect from work place, is it may be because they might have blocked port to connect?

Comment: Start with debugging DNS resolution. `nslookup YOU_HOST` or `dig YOU_HOST` will show if the host can be actually found.

Comment: Thank you, its due to port has been disabled from work place i have asked to enable and now its working fine